# Does the definition of ideal quotient $(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b})$ actually require $\mathfrak{b}$ to be an ideal?

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

It seems like the proof that $(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b}) = \{ x \in R: x b \in \mathfrak{a} \ \ \forall b \in \mathfrak{b} \}$ is an ideal does not actually depend on $\mathfrak{b}$ being an ideal, and instead only requires $\mathfrak{a}$ to be an ideal.

**Question:** Is this a correct conclusion? I.e. is the quantity $(\mathfrak{a}:S)$ well-defined for any ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ and any subset $S$ of a commutative ring with unit $R$?
$\newcommand{\ideal}{(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b})}$

**Attempt:**
**(i)** $(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b})$ is an abelian subgroup: given $x, y \in \ideal$, we have for any $b \in \mathfrak{b}$ that $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal means that $xb, yb \in \mathfrak{a} \implies xb - yb = (x-y)b \in \mathfrak{a}$. Therefore, $x,y \in \ideal \implies x-y \in \ideal$, using only the fact that $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal.

**(ii)** $\ideal$ is absorptive: we have for any $b \in \mathfrak{b}$ that, since $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal, $xb \in \mathfrak{a} \implies r(xb)=(rx)b \in \mathfrak{a}$ for all $r \in R$. Therefore $x \in \ideal \implies rx \in \ideal$ for all $r \in R$, and thus $\ideal$ is an ideal.

Since $\ideal$ is an abelian subgroup and absorptive, it is an ideal. In the above, we only appealed to the fact that $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal, and whether $\mathfrak{b}$ is an ideal or not does not seem to matter to the conclusion that $\ideal$ is an ideal. In particular, for any ideal $\mathfrak{a}$, it seems that $(\mathfrak{a}:\{1\}) = \mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: Do note that if $S$ is a subset, and $\langle S \rangle$ is the ideal generated by $S$, then $(\mathfrak{a} : S) = (\mathfrak{a} : \langle S \rangle)$.  In other words, even though the conclusion is correct, the operation doesn't really give any new results that the ideal quotient wouldn't.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh I actually didn't realize/know that, thank you! I will try to prove this when I get home, although I imagine it's probably a direct consequence of the definition of $\langle S \rangle$. Anyway this comment is very useful for understanding why $\mathfrak{b}$ is in practice assumed to be an ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\frak{a}$ is a left ideal and you want $(\frak{a}:\frak{b})$ to be a left ideal, or if you are working in a commutative ring, this is fine.

In a non-commutative ring, if you want $(\frak{a}:\frak{b})$ to be a two-sided ideal, you need $\frak{a}$ and $\frak{b}$ to be left ideals so that you can handle both $rx$ and $xr$ when $x\in(\frak{a}:\frak{b})$.  (Some weaker conditions than left ideal work for $\frak{b}$, but you do need a condition on $\frak{b}$ in the non-commutative case if you want the result to be a two-sided ideal.)